# RightBarButtonItem is not displayed in the correct location

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a UINavigationController programmatically and add my ViewController to it:

```
// wrap in a navigation controller
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myViewController)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And then add an image to navigation item:

```
let backButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: target, action: selector)
backButton.image = UIImage(named: "ic_back")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton
```

But my BarButton is not displayed in the correct location. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: That might be image problem also some times. Please check with other images. If it works well with other images, surely it's problem with image you are using

Comment: Mqke sure x and y cordinate in bar image is zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to init UIBarButton directly to UIImage or Custom View:

i.e.,

**Swift 3.0:**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "ic_back")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: target, action: selector) 

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

alloc and init `UIButton` with desired frame! set image to that button. Set content mode if required! add target on this button to handle click! then `alloc and init` `UIBarButtonItem` using `initWithCustomView` method and pass `UIButton` as parameter that you have created.

Then set navigationItem's rightBarbuttonItem to this barbutton!

Answer (score 0):

```
let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.Methodname), for: .touchUpInside)
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(item1, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button on navigation bar like this..

```
let Button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 40))
    Button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "btn.png"), for: .normal)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Button)
```

So this code is helps you to achieve your query

Answer (score -1):

Add frame to your backButton using the following code and let us know if it worked.

```
backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
```

You may change width and height acc. to your need.